# Fl Studio graphic Interface isnt responding Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, winetricks

so i was making tunes on fl studio (wine on Ubuntu 16.04) when i switched to chrome for a few mins, then when i switched back to fl when i pressed play the green marker does not move an inch although the audio plays. i cant scroll down in the playlist. there are no mixer waveform animations. its an extremely limited and difficult to work with . some one please help. thanks. (i have saved the project, but i do not want to restart fl studio because there are certain synths i don't want to loose the names/presets)

Comment: I think you're running into a WINE bug more than anything else. Remember, it's crazy that WINE even exists, let alone works as well as it does. I suggest running the program in a VM.

Answer (score 1):

Like a comment has mentioned, it may be better to run this in a virtual machine (VirtualBox would do the trick), but there are always things you can do.

So for all programs, you typically want to check WineHQ before even installing it to check and see if Wine even plays nice with the program.

If you check the [WineHQ page for FL Studio](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=178), you can see that most versions work pretty well. Since you didn't include the version you are using, I would suggest visiting that page and looking up the configuration for your version. The site usually contains a "How-To" for most apps that show how to get them working in the best possible state.

For obvious reasons, you are going to need to restart the application though.